# Accessing Indexed Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Ok this might sound really simple but is this possible in Javascript. I have an object(array) like dis

```
questions{
0:
{A:"A in index 0",
 B:"B in index 0",
 C:"C in index 0"
 },
1:
{A:"A in index 1",
 B:"B in index 1",
 C:"C in index 1"
 },
 2:
 {A:"A in index 2",
  B:"B in index 2",
  C:"C in index 2"
 }
}
```

How do i do something like

```
questions[0].A; //output : A in index 0 
questions[2].B; //output : B in index 2
```

Comment: shouldn't `questions{`   be  `questions : {`  or `questions = {`

Comment: No it doesnt, giving me an undefined error

Comment: @LightStyle - `questions.0.A` won't work.

Comment: Then it doesn't contain what you think it contains. Please show the *actual* code, what you have in the question is a syntax error.

Comment: I was actually trying to access this elements before they were populated from an ajax call. I dont understand why someone would down vote this question, I asked because I felt this was a case of associative arrays which you cannot access with this syntax

Comment: You don't understand why you got downvotes even though you just said that you didn't give all the relevant information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. You basically need to assign that to questions.

```
var questions = {
    0: {
        A: "A in index 0",
        B: "B in index 0",
        C: "C in index 0"
    },
    1: {
        A: "A in index 1",
        B: "B in index 1",
        C: "C in index 1"
    },
    2: {
        A: "A in index 2",
        B: "B in index 2",
        C: "C in index 2"
    }
}
console.log(questions[0].A); //output : A in index 0 
console.log(questions[2].B); //output : B in index 2
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/8jVHg/